# How to reference this week's Monday in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I'm looking to do a Get Records where it would only retrieve the records where the record created date is within this week (starting Monday).

I'm thinking of setting the condition to be where the created date is greater than or equal to Monday. I've seen formulas that seem to do similar things, but nothing that gives me a Monday DateTime, like this:

```
CASE(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),
4,now()+5,
5,now()+5,
6,now()+5,
7,now()+4,
now()+3
)
```

Any idea on how to reference the datetime of this past Monday?

Thanks!